# Recursively copying a file into multiple directories, if a directory does not exist in Bash

Tags: bash, directory, copy

so I need to copy the file /home/servers/template/craftbukkit.jar into every folder inside of /home/servers, Ex. /home/servers/server1, /home/servers/server2, etc.

But I only want to do it if /home/servers/whateverserveritiscurrentlyon/mods does not exsist. This is what I came up with and was wondering if it will work:

```
echo " Script to copy a file to all server directories, only if mods does not exist in that directory"

for i in /home/servers/*/; do
    if [ ! -d "$i/mods" ]; then
    cp -f /home/servers/template/craftbukkit.jar "$i"
    fi
done

echo " completed script ..."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it should work. To non-destructively test, change the `cp -f ...` line to say `echo cp -f ...` and review the output.

It could also be somewhat shortened, but it wouldn't affect efficiency much:

```
for i in /home/servers/*/
do
  [[ -d "${i}/mods" ]] || cp -f /home/servers/template/craftbukkit.jar "${i}/."
done
```